# Ionic GridSystem

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, ionic2

i want to X Y to be in the same "row" if  the screen is medium or above and x y on seperate rows if the screen is below medium. I first tried:

```html
<ion-content padding>
    <div col-sm-12 col-md-6>x</div>
    <div col-sm-12 col-md-6>y</div>
</ion-content>
```

But no matter how wide the screen is x and y always got printed in seperat rows.
Then i tried

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-col col-sm-12 col-md-6>x</ion-col>
  <ion-col col-sm-12 col-md-6>y</ion-col>
</ion-content>
```

And now x and y are printed in the same row no matter what.

What am i doing wrong?

Im using Ionic 2 and i have `bootstrap: [IonicApp]` inside my `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `<ion-col>`'s in a `<ion-row>` element. The "[Rows are horizontal groups of columns that line the columns up properly.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#how-it-works)"

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-sm-12 col-md-6>x</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-sm-12 col-md-6>y</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: hello, if i have window as narrow as possible its displaying x and y in the same row if i make the window a bit wider its doing what it in 2 rows (like it should be) if i make the screen even wider its displaying x y in a row like it should be, why isnt it working when i have the window as small as i can possible make it?

Comment: According to the docs you should use `col-` for the smallest screen size, not `col-xs-`.